# Show images that come within the HTML content in ionic 5 or angular application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making an application in Ioni. The application obtains data using the REST API and in JSON format from my server. One of the fields goes down as HTML content from the server. This is currently showing using.

```
<div class="text-align: justify" [innerHtml]="post.body| slice: 0: oculto | safeHtml"></div>
```

and within the HTML content I have images like

```
<img src="/Laravel-filemanager/example.jpg" title=""></img>
```

and I'm showing that the path points to `http: // localhost: 8100 / Laravel-filemanager / example.jpg` instead of my server's URL.

But I'm not sure how to analyze this content and replace it with the API URL prefix.

Can someone please help me? in the pipes I have the following

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to code at your backend side and pass full image path then and then you get it from ionic side.